# What is the smallest sized server the simplest rails app can be deployed to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to deploy an open source rails project for others to review. To cut costs I was hoping to deploy it on the smallest virtual server the system requirements for Ruby and RoR allowed. What is the lower bound of system requirements for deploying the simplest Rails application? I didn't see these specs where I expected to in the Ruby and RoR documentation, but it is possible I skimmed the documentation too quickly :-) . Tagging AWS relevant tags because I am deploying to an AWS EC2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how much traffic you think you need to handle. If that also is kept to a minimum-average, then the lowest I'd advocate is a 512MB system. The Ruby on Rails stack can be 50-100MB alone unless you're very careful about pruning off extras.

on AWS EC2 terms, we're talking about a [t2.nano](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/?refid=_TWITTER) (1 CPU, 512 mb)

However, if you are new on Amazon AWS, I would advise a bigger instance, the t2.micro (1 CPU, 1024 mb) since that one falls under the [AWS free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) and you should be able to run it for free for 12 months.

Comment: Just for fun, any thoughts on the size of the EBS volume? I feel like a 1gb of general purpose SSD should cover the logs and other extra data rails will generate over time. In an attempt to answer my own follow up question, you could run it literally on the smallest offering AWS has at this time and be fine, depending on usage.

Comment: 1gb should indeed be enough, provided that you enable logrotation. You could also set up CloudWatch logs under free tier, to store your logs there.